# ZonedDateTime comparison: expected: [Etc/UTC] but was: [UTC]

Tags: java, date, datetime, zoneddatetime, datetime-comparison

I was comparing two dates which seem to be equal, but they contain a different name of zones: one is `Etc/UTC`, another is `UTC`.

According to this question: [Is there a difference between the UTC and Etc/UTC time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128574/is-there-a-difference-between-the-utc-and-etc-utc-time-zones) - this two zones are the same. But my tests fail:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestZoneDateTime {

    @Test
    public void compareEtcUtcWithUtc() {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime zoneDateTimeEtcUtc = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        ZonedDateTime zoneDateTimeUtc = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        // This is okay
        assertEquals(Timestamp.from(zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.toInstant()), Timestamp.from(zoneDateTimeUtc.toInstant()));
        // This one fails
        assertEquals(zoneDateTimeEtcUtc,zoneDateTimeUtc);

        // This fails as well (of course previous line should be commented!)
        assertEquals(0, zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.compareTo(zoneDateTimeUtc));
    }
}
```

The result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2018-01-26T13:55:57.087Z[Etc/UTC]
Actual   :2018-01-26T13:55:57.087Z[UTC]
```

More specifically, I would expect, that `ZoneId.of("UTC")` would be equal to `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")`, but they aren't!

As @NicolasHenneaux [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48463269/1479414), I should probably use `compareTo(...)` method. That's good idea, but `zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.compareTo(zoneDateTimeUtc)` returns `-16` value, because of this implementation inside `ZoneDateTime`:

```
cmp = getZone().getId().compareTo(other.getZone().getId());
```

Assertion result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :-16
```

So the problem lies somewhere in `ZoneId` implementation. But I still would expect that if both zone ids are valid and both designate the same zone, then they *should* be equal.

My question is: is it a library bug, or I am doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

Several people tried to convince me that it is a *normal* behaviour, and it is *normal* that the implementation of comparison methods uses `String` id representation of the `ZoneId`. In this case I should ask, why does the following test runs okay?

```
    @Test
    public void compareUtc0WithUtc() {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        ZoneId utcZone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUtc = now.withZoneSameInstant(utcZone);
        ZoneId utc0Zone = ZoneId.of("UTC+0");
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUtc0 = now.withZoneSameInstant(utc0Zone);

        // This is okay
        assertEquals(Timestamp.from(zonedDateTimeUtc.toInstant()), Timestamp.from(zonedDateTimeUtc0.toInstant()));
        assertEquals(0, zonedDateTimeUtc.compareTo(zonedDateTimeUtc0));
        assertEquals(zonedDateTimeUtc,zonedDateTimeUtc0);
    }
```

If `Etc/UTC` **is** the same as `UTC`, then I see two options:

- compareTo/equals method shouldn't use ZoneId id, but should compare their rules
- `Zone.of(...)` is broken and should treat `Etc/UTC` and `UTC` as the same time zones.

Otherwise I don't see why `UTC+0` and `UTC` work fine.

**UPDATE-2** I have reported a bug,  ID : 9052414. Will see what Oracle team will decide.

**UPDATE-3** The bug report accepted (don't know will they close it as "won't fix" or not): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196398

Comment: are you like searching for these bugs? :)

Comment: Seriously, I didn't drink today. I've found it during my work :)

Comment: may be just a hint, I can't look right now :(, but what if equals looks at the actual String also from the zone

Comment: @Eugene of course it does! The problem is that this zones aren't equal

Comment: @Eugene, I've updated my question with narrowing the problem to the `ZoneId`

Comment: right, I thought that it could be on purpose... wonder if there is a method equalDate or equalSomething that would treat these as same. Otherwise, seems like an issue indeed

Comment: @Eugene Good idea, but no, `zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.compareTo(zoneDateTimeUtc)` returns `-16`

Comment: and... of course I would just test this against Joda, just to make sure

Comment: Related: [How to normalise ZonedDateTime so that .equals() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379995/how-to-normalise-zoneddatetime-so-that-equals-works)

Comment: @OleV.V. and how is it related?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert the `ZonedDateTime` objects to `Instant`, as the other answers/comments already told.

### `ZonedDateTime::isEqual`

Or you can use the [`isEqual` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-), which compares if both `ZonedDateTime` instances correspond to the same `Instant`:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zoneDateTimeEtcUtc = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
ZonedDateTime zoneDateTimeUtc = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

Assert.assertTrue(zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.isEqual(zoneDateTimeUtc));
```

Comment: ```isEqual``` is really a good observation! Your answer doesn't provide an exact answer to my question, but I am upvoting it for this good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The class `ZonedDateTime` uses in its `equals()`-method the comparison of inner `ZoneId`-members. So we see in that class (source code in Java-8):

```
/**
 * Checks if this time-zone ID is equal to another time-zone ID.
 * <p>
 * The comparison is based on the ID.
 *
 * @param obj  the object to check, null returns false
 * @return true if this is equal to the other time-zone ID
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
       return true;
    }
    if (obj instanceof ZoneId) {
        ZoneId other = (ZoneId) obj;
        return getId().equals(other.getId());
    }
    return false;
}
```

The lexical representations "Etc/UTC" and "UTC" are obviously different strings so the zoneId-comparison trivially yields `false`. This behaviour is described in the javadoc, so we have no bug. I stress the statement of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The comparison is based on the ID.

That said, a `ZoneId` is like a named pointer to the zone data and does not represent the data themselves.

But I assume that you rather want to compare the rules of both different zone-ids and not the lexical representations. Then ask the rules:

```
ZoneId z1 = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
ZoneId z2 = ZoneId.of("UTC");
System.out.println(z1.equals(z2)); // false
System.out.println(z1.getRules().equals(z2.getRules())); // true
```

So you could use the comparison of zone rules and the other non-zone-related members of `ZonedDateTime` (a little bit awkward).

By the way, I strongly recommend not to use "Etc/..."-identifiers because (with the exception of "Etc/GMT" or "Etc/UTC") their **offset signs are in reverse** than what is usually expected.

Another **important remark about the comparison of `ZonedDateTime`-instances**. Look here:

```
System.out.println(zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.compareTo(zoneDateTimeUtc)); // -16
System.out.println(z1.getId().compareTo(z2.getId())); // -16
```

We see that the comparison of `ZonedDateTime`-instances with same instant and local timestamp is based on the lexical comparison of zone-ids. Usually not what most users would expect. But it is no bug, too, because this behaviour is [described in the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-). This is another reason why I don't like to work with the type `ZonedDateTime`. It is inherently too complex. You should only use it for intermediate type conversions between `Instant` and the local types IMHO. This concretely means: Before you compare `ZonedDateTime`-instances, please convert them (usually to `Instant`) and then compare.

### **Update from 2018-02-01:**

The [JDK-issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196398) which was opened for this question has been closed by Oracle as "Not an issue".

Comment: now this is what I meant in the comments, there has to be a way to actually compare them... 1+

Comment: Thank you for this analysis. But we all can read source codes and read javadocs. :-)  Seriously, don't be offended :-) . This doesn't explain why `zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.compareTo(zoneDateTimeUtc)` is not equal to `0`. If zones are equal, so date-time representations with these zones should be equal as well. That is why I consider this as a bug in the impementation

Comment: @Eugene comparing rules of Zones doesn't solve the initial problem with comparing two ZonedDateTime constructed with them...

Comment: Obvious bug in java design/implementation I think. Why to use all that fancy objects if they even don't work in terms of comparison

Comment: To Meno, an additional comment: in fact I didn't use `Etc/UTC` explicitly (this is just from test). The problem came from some other code where this zone was assigned automatically without my desire...

Comment: @Andremoniy I know, this was just to say that *at least* there's a way to compare them I guess

Comment: @Eugene to compare Zones - looks like, yes, there exists a way. But it is useless, as we can not compare ZonedDateTimes...

Comment: And probably kind of this comparison `z1.getRules().equals(z2.getRules())` should be done inside `ZonedDateTime.compareTo` method instead of comparing ZoneId's.ID's. That is a bug in my opinion

Comment: You can do something like `zdt1.toInstant().equals(zdt2.toInstant()) && zdt1.getZone().getRules().equals(zdt2.getZone().getRules())` or `zdt1.withFixedOffsetZone().equals(zdt2.withFixedOffsetZone())`. It's not very elegant but works.

Comment: @Andremoniy The fact that `ZonedDateTime` implements the `Comparable`-interface calls for problems. Your wish that the comparison does a rule-based comparison of `ZoneId` is understandable but neglects a) that there is another non-temporal state like the `Chronology` and b) the comparison can break in context of deserialization (hard to understand on first glance). My personal view how useful `ZonedDateTime` is can be found [here](http://time4j.net/tutorial/zdt.html) The type `ZonedDateTime` is simply too complex in many subtile ways. Just having `Instant` and local types should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

`ZoneDateTime` should be converted to `OffsetDateTime` and then compared with `compareTo(..)` if you want to compare the time.

`ZoneDateTime.equals`  and `ZoneDateTime.compareTo` compare if the instant and the zone identifier, i.e. tth string identifying the timezone.

`ZoneDateTime` is an instant and a zone (with its id and not only an offset) while `OffsetDateTime` is an instant and a zone offset. If you want to compare the time between the two `ZoneDateTime` objects, you should use `OffsetDateTime`.

The method `ZoneId.of(..)`is parsing the string you give and transform it if needed. `ZoneId` represents the timezone and not the offset, i.e. the time shift with the GMT timezone. While `ZoneOffset` reprensents the offset.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-

> If the zone ID equals 'GMT', 'UTC' or 'UT' then the result is a ZoneId with the same ID and rules equivalent to ZoneOffset.UTC.
>
> If the zone ID starts with 'UTC+', 'UTC-', 'GMT+', 'GMT-', 'UT+' or 'UT-' then the ID is a prefixed offset-based ID. The ID is split in two, with a two or three letter prefix and a suffix starting with the sign. The suffix is parsed as a ZoneOffset. The result will be a ZoneId with the specified UTC/GMT/UT prefix and the normalized offset ID as per ZoneOffset.getId(). The rules of the returned ZoneId will be equivalent to the parsed ZoneOffset.
>
> All other IDs are parsed as region-based zone IDs. Region IDs must match the regular expression [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9~/._+-]+ otherwise a DateTimeException is thrown. If the zone ID is not in the configured set of IDs, ZoneRulesException is thrown. The detailed format of the region ID depends on the group supplying the data. The default set of data is supplied by the IANA Time Zone Database (TZDB). This has region IDs of the form '{area}/{city}', such as 'Europe/Paris' or 'America/New_York'. This is compatible with most IDs from TimeZone.

so `UTC+0` is transformed to `UTC` while Etc/UTC is kept without modification

`ZoneDateTime.compareTo` compares the string of the id (`"Etc/UTC".compareTo("UTC") == 16`). That's the reason you should use `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: `zoneDateTimeEtcUtc.compareTo(zoneDateTimeUtc)` returns `-16`.

Comment: @Andremoniy Good observation. The comparison finally delegates to `ZoneId.getId()`-comparison, see my answer.

Comment: BTW, @Nicolas, it is said in the javadoc also: ` It is "consistent with equals", as defined by Comparable`. So equals is also proper way to compare these objects

Comment: @Andremoniy The statement "consistent with equals" does not necessarily means that it is a pure temporal comparison. In fact, other non-temporal state like the lexical representation of `ZoneId` is taken into account here. As said in my answer: A `ZoneId` is semantically only a pointer with name referencing rules/data but does not represent the ruels itself. Oracle will never accept that this is a bug because they have even described in the official API in all details this strange behaviour. No chance to get it changed in Java. IMHO a design error to make `ZonedDateTime` comparable at all

Comment: @MenoHochschild *IMHO a design error to make ZonedDateTime comparable at all* - I agree!!!

Comment: @MenoHochschild But take a note please and see my update: nevertheless `UTC+0` and `UTC` are treated as equal.

Comment: @Andremoniy Good observation about `UTC+0` and `UTC`. Here Java does an inner normalization inside the class `ZoneId` but not with "Etc/...". Apparently inconsistent! But even this "feature" is described by Oracle.

Comment: @MenoHochschild it is exactly [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Exactly true, so Oracle will refuse to accept this post as a bug.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, if you want to compare instants convert to `Instant`, not `OffsetDateTime`. [`ZonedDateTime::toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--)

Comment: @BasilBourque right my explanation was not clear, I have updated it.